# Does it help to fully reset a Mac once a year to keep it "healthy"?

Tags: backup, install

So I’ve owned the MacBook Pro for about a year or so, upon looking at a list of ways to keep a a laptop healthy; was this operation in particular that stood out. To manufacture reset annually. I then circle around to my question(s), what if I were to reset my MacBook and not for selling? Would I still need to sign out of all accounts, being that I would be logging right back in after doing so? Also being this early in stages of ownership, should this be in option?

I have been really neurotic about keeping it clean and healthy since I’ve tarnished many PCs and traumatized by the aftermath.

Any glimpse of help of info pointing me in the right direction of approaching this would help! Thanks you in all in advance

Comment: I've been migrating Macs since the macOS public beta. There is really no need to do this unless macOS (or the HD/SSD) is severely damaged and you need to re-install. If you are having problems with your Mac start a new question and detail the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Resetting your MacBook Pro to factory settings each year definitely should not be necessary. I do not personally experience any performance problems or functionality problems even though I haven't "reset" in a decade (i.e. I migrate my existing system over when I buy new hardware).

If you do chose to factory reset, which I wouldn't recommend, you would need to sign into iCloud again after reinstalling. If you have your Keychain synced to iCloud, you don't need to start from scratch in amassing passwords and logins. However, you would probably need to login into various stuff once again (like for example login to Adobe subscriptions, Office 365 subscriptions, mail subscriptions, etc.).

Comment: So you’re saying that resetting the MacBook would only be relevant when assessing  a major issue from worsening or happening? I’ve noticed that they are waaay more “durable” per say, to a windows or PC. I had malware from the moment I went and ‘installed’ the apps/ software via web browser. Taking into a Apple, they found numerous adware and malware situations but were able to back track to before it happened.” If this were to happen to a PC,” specialist said. “No offense to Windows, but it would have been toast by now.” I now feel proud to own this beautiful machine. Thank you Jksoegaard

Comment: I would actually never reset. If I had a major issue that couldn't be fixed (such as for example a malware infection) - I would restore from a Time Machine backup from before it happened. Resetting is nice when selling the machine to someone else for example.

Comment: FWIW, I always upgrade by installing the latest version of macOS from scratch rather than using the standard upgrade procedure. My rationale is that it prevents unused files from lingering due to migration bugs, it gets me to review what software and files I have, and ensures I have a backup taken at least every year.

Comment: OP, the only reason people suggest wiping a device thoroughly before selling it is to reduce the chance of the buyer having access to your data. It is also recommended that people wipe used devices when buying them to prevent them from becoming the victims of malware that was set up by a malicious seller before they acquire the device.

Comment: Also, don't fall folly to the claim that malware targeting non-Windows platforms isn't effective — it is, and there are plenty of bad things you can end up with on your Mac. However, with Windows being much more prevalent, malicious actors tend to focus their efforts on that platform, so you're less likely to end up with something like that by chance.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS does not need any user 'maintenance', under normal operation. You don't need to clean, restore, reset, wipe or purge anything. No oil change required after 10,000 miles.

There are two main reasons why your Mac might start to slow down or crash, etc: Running out of disk space; and third-party software that is no longer compatible with newer OS versions.

Make sure you keep around 15-20% of your disk as free space; and keep everything up-to-date and be slightly conservative about what you install.